# Align text and numeric values by decimal in table body using dcolumn

Tags: tables, dcolumn

How can I align numeric values in the body of my table by decimal point when some of those values are accompanied by character values? For example, say I wanted to report some standard deviations in a column aligned by decimal point such that each one is enclosed in parentheses. How can I do things like this?

**Update** Based on answer by David Carlisle

```
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lD{.}{.}{7.4}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Test 2} \\
    \midrule
    Test & \mathrm{abcde}(1.23)\\
    Test2 & (4.321)\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *always* helps if you provide a document showing the problem, but basically `dcolumn` doesn't really mind about extra characters. `(12.3)` and `12.3` would both be aligned on the `.`  If you use the centre on `.` form then there is nothing else to do; if you use the form `D{.}{.}{3.2}` to specify the space before and after the `.` you just need to specify enough space for the text parts, specified in multiples of the width of a digit.